# Make file: compiling all .cpp files to .o files

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a make file which will compile all the `.cpp` files in the `test` directory to `.o` files in the `obj` directory.  Below is an abridged version of what I am doing.  The problem is that the calls made to compile to the `.o` files have the proper `.o` name, but they all are compiling the same `.cpp` file.

```
gcc -c -o obj/foo.o test/foo.c
gcc -c -o obj/bar.o test/foo.c
gcc -c -o obj/baz.o test/foo.c
```

What do I need to change to make it compile the corresponding `.cpp` file?

```
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard test/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst test/%.cpp,obj/%.o,$(CPP_FILES))


obj/%.o: $(CPP_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

executable : $(OBJ_FILES) foo.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to match `%` for your template rule. at the moment you are saying that every .o depends on **every** cpp file. And `$<` is the first of them.

Replace it with:

```
obj/%.o : test/%.cpp
```